# Cocoa pods error on specifying source

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate pod with my project. I need to specify source per pod. Everything works just fine when I'm specifying global source like that:

```
source 'https://github.com/MyRepo/MySpec.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TestProject' do
  pod 'MyTestSDKSpec'
end
```

However when I'm trying to specify source per pod like that:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TestProject' do
  pod 'MyTestSDKSpec', git: 'https://github.com/MyRepo/MySpec.git'
end
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `MyTestSDKSped` from `https://github.com/MyRepo/MySpec.git`
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'MyTestSDKSpec'.
```

Can you please tell why I'm getting such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your `Podfile`, try doing this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TestProject' do
  pod 'MyTestSDKSpec', :git => 'https://github.com/MyRepo/MySpec.git'
end
```

Comment: That's not this. When I'm doing this I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: yeah... I messed up my own answer.  Use `:git` and NOT `git:`.